# como usar o método array.find para encontrar um atributo de um array que é formado pelo conteúdo do localStorage?

Tags: javascript, array, localstorage

Tenho um array vazio que recebe via push o conteúdo do localstorage (que é um array também),

porém, quando vou dar um vetor.find para encontrar o valor de um atributo, como o _nome, ele não retorna o resultado, apresentando o erro undefined.

```
const vetor = []

vetor.push(window.localStorage.getItem ('localCadastro'));

const resultado = vetor.find (atributo => atributo._nome == 'teste');
```

quando dou um **console.log (vetor)**, o resultado é esse:

```
["[{\"_cpf\":\"\",\"_conta\":\"\",\"_nome\":\"teste\"}]"]
```

mas quando dou um **console.log (resultado)**, o resultado é esse:

```
undefined
```

Quero usar o find para encontrar um conteudo especifico no array que está no localStorage.

**ps: utilizo o window.localStorage por estar tentando consultar o localStorage da index.html e o localstorage estar sendo salvo em uma outrapagina.html.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `localStorage` não armazena *arrays* ou *objetos*, ele armazena apenas *strings*.

Veja que o item `localCadastro` está sendo retornado como uma *string*, não como um *array*, você deveria estar fazendo o parse desse valor para obter o array:

```
const vetor = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('localCadastro'));
```

Também não há a necessidade de fazer `push`, pois você estaria inserindo um array dentro de outro array, o que acredito que não seja o seu objetivo.

Agora você pode fazer o find normalmente, como você mesmo colocou na pergunta:

```
const resultado = vetor.find(atributo => atributo._nome == 'teste');
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!